# How to get Crontab running using a script instead of adding an entry using crontab -e

Tags: linux, bash, cron, firmware

Previously I wrote an script to be executed every minute using Cronjob.
Using `crontab -l` I added an entry  like :

```
* * * * * /etc/init.d/time-stamps-ntp
```

to execute the mentioned script periodically. Now; I would like to do this process automatically for some other devices using firmware update. I do not have any access to those devices to be able to set or edit crontab. I want to add some commands to one of the rauc scripts which is responsible for updating the firmware of those devices.

How should I do this or can you please tell me when we use crontab -e , in which file the following entry is saved?

```
* * * * * /etc/init.d/time-stamps-ntp
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you add an entry using `crontab -l`? I think you mean `crontab -e`.

Comment: If you can't access the crontab (i.e. you have not rights to access the computer which is running the cron-demon), or if you don't have the permissions, you are out of luck. It is a bit like asking how to login if you don't know the password.